# Appium - I'm getting null message while taking screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, appium

I'm new to automation.
I'm getting null message while taking screenshot.

TestNG listener code

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
    //write screenshot codes here
    String s=arg0.getName();
    try {
        Base.getScreenshot(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Base class screenshot method

```
        public static void getScreenshot(String s) throws IOException
        {
        try{
        
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);              
        // Copy files to specific location
        // arg0.getName() will return name of test case so that screenshot name will be same as test case name
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+s+".png"));
        System.out.println("Successfully captured a screenshot");
        }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());
        }
        
}
```

I have manually failed the test using some incorrect locator to call the tentNG failure and when taking screenshot it retrieved null message as below

Output:
Exception while taking screenshot null

Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

I'm blocked at the moment :(

Comment: add the way you run tests in question

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); & check if driver is null or not

Comment: Thanks @RahulL the driver is null, I've initialized it twice and hence the issue. 
I've now removed the initialization and it worked perfectly